# Uniqueness of morphism from reflexive graph to indiscrete reflexive relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

In the book *From Groups to Categorical Algebra* by Dominique Bourn, an exercise is to prove that given a reflexive graph $R$ on an object $X$, there is a unique morphism of reflexive graphs $(f, \bar f)$ from $R$ to the indiscrete reflexive relation on $X$. Attempting to solve this, it seems to me that any pair $(g, (gd_0, gd_1))$ would work where  $d_0$ and $d_1$ are the domain and codomain of the graph and $g: X\to X$. Is this a mistake in the book or a mistake in Carla?

Comment: Having just glanced at the relevant section, I think this is a mistake in the book. Hopefully someone with more experience (e.g. someone who's actually read this book) can confirm!

Comment: @tkf If we restrict to those pairs where the right side morphism is identity, there indeed seems to be an unique one. But in general there's one for each endomorphism of $X$ right?

Comment: @CcVHKakalLLOOPPOkKkkKk Thanks I see what the OP was saying now (+1).  Also, for any $g$ the splittings are forced to commute, by a bit of diagram chasing.

Comment: @tkf (i am OP's other account)